# Calling a Google Cloud function from a web app on Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'd like to launch a Flask-based web app on Google Cloud Platform's App Engine, which has the ability to call a Cloud Function, written in python. References to do these things independently below:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python

However, calling a cloud function from a (python) web app hosted on App Engine seems to be under documented. Could anyone link a resource that has accomplished this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this answer, I will list example documents to understand authorization in Google Cloud and how to call Cloud Functions from App Engine. Read these links/documents and understand how everything works and is connected together. Once you understand the basics, authorization in Google Cloud is very easy to implement and secure.

**Step 1 - Understand Authorization in Google Cloud**

Google Cloud uses OAuth for most services and APIs. Some services still support API Keys. Read this article to get a foundation of Server/Service to Server/Service Authorization:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account)

Key points to understand are Access Tokens and Identity Tokens. Another token type is the Refresh Token which is primarily used to refresh OAuth tokens created from user credentials.

**Step 2 - Understand the JWTs used for Authorization**

This article is written for IoT devices but the details are the same/similar for all Google Cloud services. This link includes sample code.

[Using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs)](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/jwts)

**Step 3 - Understand Cloud Functions Authorization**

Cloud Functions uses OAuth Identity Tokens to authorize requests from other services and users. An OAuth Identity Token is a signed JWT that asserts the identity of the caller. Identity Tokens are signed by a Google owned or managed private key and verified by Google before granting access to the called Cloud Function.

[Authenticating Developers, Functions, and End-users](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating)

**Step 4 - Understand how to call another service from App Engine Standard**

Now that you understand how authorization is performed in Google Cloud, you need to understand how to create the token used for authorized calls to your Cloud Function. This article discusses App Identity in Python and how to assert an identity to call Cloud Functions or any Google API/Service from App Engine Standard.

[App Identity Python API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity)